# Replace start of line with multiple space characters in front of a String in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to append 10 spaces to a new line at the beginning of the string:

```
string = "\nHello"
```

should be changed to:

```
"\n           Hello"
```

Tried following and other ways but in vain

```
string.gsub!("\n", "\n(\s){10}")
#=> "\n( ){10}Hello"
```

and

```
string.gsub!("\n", "\n[\s]{10}")
#=> "\n[ ]{10}Hello"
```

Comment: \s\s\s\s\..10 times work, but I want to replace it with candid notation so I used regex  \s{10} but it did not work

Comment: Do you want to replace `\n` with 10 spaces or do you want to prepend (or maybe append?) 10 spaces to `\n`? And do you just want to replace `\n` if it occurs at the beginning of the string or regardless of its position?

Comment: To be precise , beginning. Want to replace \n with \n10spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use gsub, keep the matched element and append "n" whitespaces.

```
string = "\nHello"
p string.gsub(/\n/) { |match| "#{match}#{' ' * 20}" }
# "\n                    Hello"
```

Or if you want just replace them:

```
string.gsub(/\n/, ' ' * 20)
```

If you want to limit the \n to the first character in the string, then the first argument for gsub would be `\A\n`.

I think the more accurate to what you were trying would be:

```
string.gsub(/(\n)/, "#{$1}#{' ' * 20}")
```

Or if knowing \n can be at any place and you just care on appending the X \s:

```
string.gsub(/\n/, "\n#{"\s" * 20}")
```

Comment: Is this part `\s*20` a Ruby code that should be executed?

Comment: Oops, finally this worked for me gsub!(/\n/, "\n#{' ' * 20}")

Comment: Thanks for your clue